# Flutter iOS : Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: ios, flutter

My flutter app is crashing with an error "**Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue**" while running on iPhone 6 plus device. The crash occurs when we scroll the list with images. The sample project which demonstrates the crash is available [Here](https://github.com/shyjuzz/flutter-samples/tree/master/crash_test)

**The code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

final images = [
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventurboapp.appspot.com/o/userposts%2F2019-09-14T19%3A42%3A13.717163.jpg?alt=media&token=733bf554-168b-4ef3-ac91-b7e4911a5531',
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventurboapp.appspot.com/o/userposts%2F2019-08-26T15%3A11%3A41.359199.jpg?alt=media&token=c3d7876a-28c4-4800-aa85-39c980b5dc5',
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventurboapp.appspot.com/o/userposts%2F2019-08-26T15%3A03%3A12.813399.jpg?alt=media&token=e0ba4903-0282-43f2-94bf-1f841a7c7d33',
  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/eventurboapp.appspot.com/o/userposts%2F2019-08-22T16%3A00%3A28.429855.jpg?alt=media&token=915b9ea8-8370-4ff0-aaa6-89c23c28b89b'
];

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //var list = new List<int>.generate(60, (i) => i + 1);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: images.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('$index'),
                        Center(
                          child: CachedNetworkImage(
                            placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            imageUrl: images[index],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          )), 
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me to find a solution why this is happening even if we use CachedNetworkImage ?

Comment: You have a crash with only 4 images?

Comment: @CZ54 Yes, while scrolling up and down

Answer (score 0):

Flutter crashing with four images being displayed seems to be a bug. However, since this post is old, upgrading to the latest version of Flutter should be the first step for troubleshooting. Running the latest version of Flutter should also help identify the cause of the issue. Run `flutter upgrade` on the Terminal to upgrade the Flutter version in your machine.

Another workaround that can be used is by limiting the image cache as mentioned on this [thread](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/260).